# AVAudioConverter Compressed/PCM conversion throwing OSStatus -50 (kAudio_ParamError)

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to use AVAudioConverter to convert compressed audio data (in this case mp3, 96kbps, CBR, stereo) into PCM data (the standard output format, obtained by calling audioEngine.outputNode.outputFormatForBus(0)). I use an AudioFileStream to get the packets. I have previously used an AudioQueue to play these packets, so they are valid.

This is where I call convertToBuffer:

```
let outputBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: outputBufferFrameLength)  
outputBuffer.frameLength = outputBufferFrameLength  
var error:NSError?  
audioConverter.convertToBuffer(outputBuffer, error: &error, withInputFromBlock: { (packetCount:AVAudioPacketCount, inputStatus:UnsafeMutablePointer<AVAudioConverterInputStatus>) -> AVAudioBuffer? in  
    return self.getAudioConverterInput(packetCount, inputStatus: inputStatus)  
})  
if let error = error{  
    print("conv error:", error)  
}else{  
    // TODO: Do stuff with buffer  
}
```

And this is the function that handles the input.

```
func getAudioConverterInput(packetCount:AVAudioPacketCount, inputStatus:UnsafeMutablePointer<AVAudioConverterInputStatus>) -> AVAudioBuffer?{  
        if let currentAudioFormat = currentAudioFormat, firstPackets = packets.first{  
            inputStatus.memory = .HaveData  
            let buffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer(format: currentAudioFormat, packetCapacity: packetCount, maximumPacketSize: Int(currentMaximumPacketSize))  
            var currentPackets:Packets = firstPackets  
            var currentStartOffset:Int64 = 0  
            for i in 0..<packetCount{  
                let currentDescription = currentPackets.packetDescriptions[currentPacket]  
                memcpy(buffer.data.advancedBy(Int(currentStartOffset)), currentPackets.data.advancedBy(Int(currentDescription.mStartOffset)), Int(currentDescription.mDataByteSize))  
                buffer.packetDescriptions[Int(i)] = AudioStreamPacketDescription(mStartOffset: currentStartOffset, mVariableFramesInPacket: currentDescription.mVariableFramesInPacket, mDataByteSize: currentDescription.mDataByteSize)  

                currentStartOffset += Int64(currentDescription.mDataByteSize)  
                currentPacket+=1  

                if (currentPackets.numberOfPackets == UInt32(currentPacket)){  
                    currentPacket = 0  
                    packets.removeFirst()  
                    if let firstPackets = packets.first{  
                        currentPackets = firstPackets  
                    }else{  
                        buffer.packetCount = i + 1  
                        return buffer  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
            buffer.packetCount = packetCount  
            return buffer  
        }  
        inputStatus.memory = .NoDataNow  
        return nil  
    }
```

This function is called once every time I call the convertToBuffer(...) function with the packetCount variable set to '1'. The error "conv error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"" is thrown.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you resolved the issue. if it so, could you post the fix. i am trying in objective-c, i am also getting the same error -50.

Comment: No, sadly I haven't, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you could but your inputStatus.memory = .HaveData  in the input block before you call getAudioConverterInput?